# Connect ViewController to .swift file in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

As you can see in the image below, my View Controller (a Table view controller if that matters) is named "BasicPhrasesVC" and my .swift file is also named "BasicPhrasesVC". Despite this the error "Unknown class BasicPhrasesVC in Interface Builder file." keeps appearing. I also did not rename them if it helps.

[image: View Controller Problems Image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your BasicPhrasesVC.swift, the code should be something like this

```
class BasicPhrasesVC {
  ....
}
```

the **Class in your Interface builder** should be the same as the **class same** in your file, it doesn't matter where you place your class.
At last, after you fix your class name, in your interface builder Custom Class -> Class, input the correct name and "**press Enter**"

Comment: The code is currently 
'code' class BasicPhrases: UITableViewController {
...
}'code'
will changing it to 
    class BasicPhrasesVC: UITableViewController {
...
}'code'
work?

Comment: type your class name in your xcode interface builder(Custom Class -> Class) "again" and press "Enter", the text in the module field should be something like: "Current..." or something else, the module name in your question is "None", it means that xcode can't pair your class  to your interface object